# CreateProcess вылетает при передаче команды длинной более 63 символов

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, процесс

```
char text[] = "schtasks.exe /create /tn abc /sc daily /tr calc.exe /st 12:00\0";
size_t size = strlen(text) + 1;
wchar_t* wtext = new wchar_t[size];
size_t outSize;
mbstowcs_s(&outSize, wtext, size, text, size-1);
LPWSTR ptr = wtext;

if (CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\schtasks.exe", ptr, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0 , NULL, NULL, &startup, &process_info))
```

Такой код работает и создаёт задачу, но стоит мне увеличить длину строки `text`, к примеру вместо `/tn abc` написать `/tn abcd`, программа вылетает на функции `CreateProcessW`. Никаких ошибок не выводит, просто `The program has unexpectedly finished.`. Не могу понять, в чём ошибка, может кто помочь?

**UPD:** заменил mbstowcs на mbstowcs_s, теперь функция выполняется успешно, но при этом не происходит создание задачи, независимо от длинны команды

Comment: Попробуйте явно добавить терминирующий ноль в wtext...

Comment: Записал так char text[] = "schtasks.exe /create /tn abcd /sc daily /tr calc.exe /st 12:00\0"; Странно, но она стала принимать на один символ больше, т.е. abcd работает, но стоит добавить ещё один символ и она вылетает

Comment: sizeof убрал, не помню когда и добавил его, но суть не меняется от этого

Comment: А зачем вообще конвертировать? `wchar_t wtext[] = L"schtasks.exe /create /tn abc /sc daily /tr calc.exe /st 12:00\0"` разве не годится?

Comment: Мне надо будет изменять эту строку, поэтому не вариант

Comment: Не исключили отсутствие терминирующего нуля - пляшите дальше с непонятными багами.

Comment: Так я же добавил его сразу после вашего комментария

Comment: Хорошо, я добавил его явно к wtext, после преобразования, но ошибка не пропала

Comment: Зачем в строковый литерал вы явно вписали `\0`??? Ноль вам предлагали добавить в `wtext`. В `text` добавлять ноль никакого смысла нет - он там и так присутствует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моё решение:

```
bool Net::executeCommand(QString exe, QString command, LPDWORD lp)
{
    // игнорировать предупреждения о non-initialized fields в si
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-field-initializers"
    STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(si),0,};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    auto chr = strdup(command.toStdString().c_str());
    size_t cSize = strlen(chr)+1;
    wchar_t wc[cSize];
    mbstowcs(wc, chr, cSize);
    LPWSTR ptr = wc;

    // осталось обрабатывать ошибки как - то
    if (CreateProcess(reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(exe.utf16()), ptr, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        delete[] ptr;
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, lp); // парсер ошибки

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        delete[] ptr;
        qDebug() << GetLastError();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Поле cb в STARTUPINFOW должно содержать корректное значение. Остальные поля STARTUPINFO и PROCESS_INFORMATION лучше обнулить.

Answer (score 1):

Не забыли обнулить startup и process_info?

```
ZeroMemory(&startup , sizeof(startup));
startup.cb = sizeof(startup);
ZeroMemory(&process_info, sizeof(process_info));
```

[1]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Нет, не забыл, но спасибо