# Помогите создать задачу в планировщике с помощью CreateProcess

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, процесс, параметры

Связанный вопрос - [CreateProcess вылетает при передаче команды длинной более 63 символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731934/createprocess-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-63-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2). Мою реализацию, которая не работает, можно увидеть тут.

Не могли бы вы написать функцию, которая создаст задачу с такими аргументами: `schtasks.exe /create /s PC-NAME /tn test /tr \"C:\\windows\\system32\\perfmon /report \" /sc DAILY /st 12:00:00 /f`, или, хотя бы, подсказать что я делаю не так.

Мои попытки:

```
    STARTUPINFOW si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    char text[] = "schtasks.exe /create /tn abcd /sc daily /tr calc.exe /st 
12:00\0";
    size_t size = strlen(text) + 1;
    wchar_t* wtext = new wchar_t[size+1];
    size_t outSize;
    mbstowcs_s(&outSize, wtext, size, text, size-1);
    wtext[size+1] = '\0';
    LPWSTR ptr = wtext;
    LPCWSTR ded = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\schtasks.exe";

    if (CreateProcessW(ded, ptr, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0 , NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(&si);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
    else
        qDebug() << GetLastError();
```

Я тут и с `'\0'` и с преобразованиями игрался, ничего не помогает.

Comment: Ваш код не является минимально необходимым для воспроизведения проблемы. startup - непонятно что и что с ним происходит.

Comment: Добавил недостающий код, прошу прощения

Comment: Ваши строковые "преобразования" не совсем понятны. Попробуйте реализовать чисто константами - для того что б нивелировать ошибки преобразования.

Comment: Я проверял после преобразования строки, и через константы писал. Только что попробовал ещё раз, уж код кидать не буду, но всё равно не работает

Comment: А char text[] = "schtasks.exe ... зачем у вас? Вы же в другом параметре указываете что запускать...

Comment: В первом параметре указывается исполняемый файл, а во втором его параметры. С MSDN:  If both lpApplicationName and lpCommandLine are non-NULL, the null-terminated string pointed to by lpApplicationName specifies the module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by lpCommandLine specifies the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант, concat_period возвращает QString, а str объявляется чуть раньше, это тоже QString. Если кто будет использовать, не забудьте освободить память chr и wc\ptr

```
    STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(si),0,};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    auto chr = strdup((concat_period(str, period, 60) + "/rl HIGHEST").toStdString().c_str());
    size_t cSize = strlen(chr)+1;
    wchar_t wc[cSize];
    mbstowcs(wc, chr, cSize);
    LPWSTR ptr = wc;

// осталось обрабатывать ошибки как - то
    if (CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\schtasks.exe", ptr, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(&si);
        LPDWORD lp;
        GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, lp);
        qDebug() << (int)lp;
    }
    else
        qDebug() << GetLastError();
```

Answer (score 1):

Поле cb в STARTUPINFOW должно содержать корректное значение. Остальные поля STARTUPINFO и PROCESS_INFORMATION лучше обнулить.

Comment: Добавил `si.cb = sizeof(si);`, не помогло